# alert if option value is empty using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on a add to cart button for products with attributes that can be selected via select list. Upon clicking on add to cart button I would like to check if any option is selected. If not - display an alert, if yes fly product to basket. 
I am using this code for jquery 1.3.2

```
 if($('#category option').length === 0) {
alert("Please choose some option");
}
else 
{
```

However, it is not working at all. Please see full code here http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Pry/92/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `.val` property

```
if( $('#category').val() === '' )
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Z7Pry/93/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
if ($('#categoryoption:selected').length) {
    // blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('#category')[0].value) {
     alert("Please choose some option");
} else {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
 if($('#category-option').val() != '') {
CODE HERE FOR MOVING TO CART
}
else 
{
alert("Please choose an option");
}
```